# I wonder what is happening in this Java code block

Tags: java

```
Objectname.methodone()
.methodtwo()
.methodthree()
.methodfour();
```

Are these statements above same as

```
Objectname.methodone();
Objectname.methodtwo();
Objectname.methodthree();
Objectname.methodfour();
```

Thanks,

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872222/how-to-do-method-chaining-in-java-o-m1-m2-m3-m4

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the return types of `methodone`, `methodtwo`, `methodthree` and `methodfour`. What's going on is you're calling `methodone` on `Objectname`, `methodtwo` on the return type of `methodone` and so on.

If `methodone` through `methodfour` all return `this`, then yes, it would be the same.

This is referred to as [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, if the implementation of each of those methods ends with `return this;` so that the calls can be chained like that.  But it's possible that each returns a reference to a *different* object, on which the "next" method is then called.

Answer (score 0):

no its not like that it is as

```
    Objectname.methodone().methodtwo().methodthree().methodfour();
```

similar to the

```
 result = method1().method2(). ........ method n()
```

its called **method chaining**

refer [Method chaining in Java](http://www.javasync.com/2009/08/method-chaining-in-java-strings.html)

**EXAMPLE**

```
class Person
{
        private final String name;
        private int age;

        public Person setName(final String name) {
                this.name = name;

                return this;
        }

        public Person setAge(final int AGE) {
                this.age = AGE;

                return this;
        }

        public void introduce() {
                System.out.println("Hello, my name is " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old.");
        }

        // Usage:
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Person person = new Person();
                // Output of this sequence will be: Hello, my name is Peter and I am 21 years old.
                person.setName("Peter").setAge(21).introduce();
        }
}
```

source :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, `methodtwo` is called on the return value of `methodone` and `methodthree` is called on the return value of `methodtwo` and so on. They are not (necessarily) called on the same object.

The equivalent is:

```
MethodOneReturnType x = object.methodone();
MethodTwoReturnType y = x.methodtwo();
MethodThreeReturnType z = y.methodthree();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what those methods return. methodtwo is being called on the return of methodone. if methodone returns Objectname, then they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

it is very unlikely they'll be same. Think of a pizza builder.

```
new PizzaBuilder().withDough("dough").withSauce("sauce").withTopping("topping").build();
```

this builds the complete pizza. whereas if you call the with methods separately it will build only a partial pizza.