# What is this multiple '.' syntax?

Tags: java

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setMessage(mymessage)
  .setTitle(title)
  .setCancelable(true)
  .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}
     })
  .show();
```

Hi, could someone explain what this java language feature is called, to be able to call methods without directly specifying the object before the '.' ?

I would like to read more about how to use this...

and does it only work with "new" or can I use existing objects with this syntax?

Comment: there is actually an object before each '.' if you put it on a single line you can see it clearer. new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(mymessage).setTitle(title).setCancelable(true)

Comment: ok, I'm an idiot it is method chaining.. (well at least now I know this term, although I had used that functionality many times before)... I had just been confused because there are AlertDialog.Builder and AlertDialog objects and I looked at the docs of AlertDialog which had many of the same methods like .setMessage... except that in AlertDialog it returns void but in AlertDialog.Builder returns a Builder object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code is terminated by the semicolon. What you have there is (formatting-aside) identical to:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(mymessage).setTitle(title).setCancelable(true).setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}}).show();
```

I think you'll agree that the linebreaks make it more readable!

Now, each one of those methods in the chain is implemented as returning `this` as a useful "side effect" (in the intent sense, rather than functional sense) - this means that `myBuilder.setMessage(myMessage)` returns the modified myBuilder, which you're then free to use `.setTitle(title)` on, et cetera.

Answer (score 6):

This is called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

It does not require any special support from the Java language. Each of the functions in question (`setMessage()`, `setTitle()` etc) simply returns `this`, thereby allowing the chaining.

For more information, see [How to do method chaining in Java? o.m1().m2().m3().m4()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872222/how-to-do-method-chaining-in-java-o-m1-m2-m3-m4)

> does it only work with "new" or can I use existing objects with this syntax

Provided the methods return `this`, this technique can be used with or without `new`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called **method chaining**.

And you actually are calling the methods on an object:

`new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` returns an object.

Call `setMessage(mymessage)` on that object and you get another object, and so on.

Comment: that is what I thought... but in the android docs it shows that these methods (At least the ones I looked at) return void... but when I paste the text into my java IDE, it passes syntax checking (no red squiggles) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: @ycomp the return type is void or it returns a null object?

Comment: oh.. I think I'm looking at wrong object.. lol there are AlertDialog.Builder and AlertDialog objects. It is method chaining.. pity, I thought I'd discovered some equivalent of a "with" statement for java, lol

Answer (score 1):

[Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Each method returns a reference back to itself which allows you to call another method on it and so forth. jQuery uses this a lot in the JavaScript world.

Answer (score 1):

It is chainable syntax, it can be used with any object whose methods return this object.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the point
whitespace is ignored in most languages' code files therefore what you see is actually one long line split for readability

```
 new alertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(mymessage).setTitle(title).setCancelable(true).setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}}).show();
```

you get the point