# Java method chaining

Tags: java, methods, chaining

I have a line of data that contains various non-delimited field values.

```
X55655PlateX58745CupX52689SaucerX52459SpoonH59876KnifeX59866Fork
```

I am trying to use substring and indexOf to pull the data, using a series of statements similar to the one below.

```
dataField1 = substring.inputLine((indexOf("Marker1: ")+9),(inputLine.indexOf("Marker2:")-1));
```

I keep getting `error:cannot find symbol` pointing to `substring`. Typically, this is when I've not called the proper java packages in, but I'm using the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.lang.*;
```

and `java.lang.*` is where the string methods live, right? I'm also initializing `String datafield1 = "";`.

```
dataField1 = inputLine.Substring((indexOf("Marker1: ")+9),(indexOf("Marker2:")-1));
```

results in indexOf receiveing the `cannot find symbnol` error. But if indexOf is ALSO a method of String, where would that need to go?

My program appears to be using the proper syntax `substring(x,y)` as noted in the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), however, there are no real-world examples applicable to my troubleshooting.

I've reviewed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872222/how-to-do-method-chaining-in-java-o-m1-m2-m3-m4) but it doesn't quite get me to wrap my head around the concepts any better.

Why dioes this keep erroring out, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: `inputLine.Substring` should have a lower case **s** for `substring`.  i.e. `inputLine.substring(...` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Generally, you don't need to import `java.lang`, as it's imported 'by default' (given it contains `Object`).  But, isn't this a good case for actually using `Pattern`/`Matcher` (regex) combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`substring` should be called on a String object.  Otherwise it is looking for a method called `substring` in your current class.

Answer (score 4):

[`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is a method of `String`, should be:

```
inputLine.substring(...
```

assuming `inputLine` is a `String` instance.

Comment: Thanks! When I do that, then indexOf becomes the unknown symbol. If indexOf is also a method of String...where would that need to go?

Comment: @dwwilson66, `inputLine.indexOf()`, as usual already have following the first call.

Comment: You had it correct in your second use of indexOf just missed the `inputLine.` before the first call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String dataField1 = inputLine.substring((inputLine.indexOf("Marker1: ")+9),
                                        (inputLine.indexOf("Marker2:")-1));
```

Comment: you ought to explain why what you are doing makes the code valid rather than just rewriting code.  This helps the OP to understand what he/she was doing wrong.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c Actually...I think I see it...because substring and indexOf are both methods of String, I need to call them from my string in both instances: inputline.substring AND inputline.indexOf. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Methods must be called on the object otherwise it looks for the method defined in your class.  Since substring is not a method in your class it `cannot find the symbol`