# How to nest methods in java to force user to use the nested name?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm writing a library, for more readability I want to force user to use nested methods to call the correct functions.

For example this is my class looks like:

```java
public class Foo{
public void methodA(){}
public void methodB(){}
public void methodC(){}
}
```

What I'm expecting the user:

```java
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.methodA.methodB();
foo.methodA.methodC();
```

to call method B & C through calling the methodA as a prefix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872222/how-to-do-method-chaining-in-java-o-m1-m2-m3-m4. See this link

Comment: You can't nest methods in Java.

Comment: Kindly see edited answer by me! hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the user to use methodA to access methodB you could use an inner class.
In methodB you can access the Foo-Object with Foo.this.

```
public class Foo{
   public Bar methodA()
   {
       // ...
       return new Bar();
   }

   public class Bar {

      private Bar() {}; // only methodA can create a Bar object

      public void methodB(){}
      public void methodC(){}

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question i think you are asking about Builder Design patten in which every methods return type is same class object and you can make call hierarchy like this.

```
obj.aMethod().bMethod().cMethod();
```

in your example just do like this:

```
public class Foo{
 private static final Foo instance = new Foo();
 private Foo(){}

 public static Foo getInstance(){
    return instance;
 }

 public Foo methodA(){
  //Do stuff 
  return getInstance();
 }
 public Foo methodB(){}
 public Foo methodC(){}
}
```

Now you can call like `objfoo.getInstance().methodA().methodB();`

Hope it will help you. [To read more about that pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)

Comment: Thanks but this is not builder pattern. I'm trying to force user so he/she can't call methodB directly and has to go through methodA

Comment: Oh OK then you have to return object of same class in methodA and then you can call any method with that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is called as method chaining. You will need to set the return type of all methods as the same as the Class.

```
public class Foo{ 
public Foo methodA()
public Foo methodB() 
public Foo methodC() 
}
```

Now the client can simply call:

```
foo.methodA().methodB(), etc.
```

You can have one "terminal method" i.e. one that does not return a value. For example

```
public void methodD();
```

This method will be called last.

```
foo.methodA().methodB().methodC().method();
```

This line in itself will be valid as return type is void.

Please look at method chaining/ builder pattern YouTube videos, it will be clear.