# Why would a java function return an object that has been passed to it as a parameter?

Tags: java

I am looking at some piece of code and wonder why the author uses a scheme like this:

```
SomeObject modifyObject(SomeObject o){
    SomeObject p = o;
    
    //do some magic that modifies p
    
    return p;
}

var SomeObject x = SomeObject();
x = modifyObject(x);
```

rather than

```
void modifyObject(SomeObject o){
    
    //do some magic that modifies o

}

var SomeObject x = SomeObject();
modifyObject(x);
```

I did a few tests and both version seem to work just the same. What am I missing?

Edit: seems like I really have three (related or not) questions posted as one:

- Why return SomeObject and not void?

  --> To support method chaining. Thanks a lot, I did not think of this as this method is not used that way anywhere.
- Why assign the parameter o to a local variable p, rather than work with o directly (this is not a raw type, so both o and p reference and modify the same object)?

  --> Unnecessary, since no new object is ever created. Probably an attempt to "improve" readability (which did not work for me.).
- Why assign the result of calling the method to the same variable again that was passed in as a parameter already?

  --> Another attempt at improving readability?

Comment: We can only guess what the purpose of this is. You should either ask the author of the code, or give more context about what this method is doing.

Comment: The first version returns `p` which is the same as `o` (because of the assignment on the first line)

Comment: I'm guessing whoever wrote the code didn't know that their function modifies the object in place, judging by the `SomeObject p = o;` line. Then again this is so far simplified that who knows what the original code actually does.

Comment: They _might_ have mistakenly thought they were doing a shallow copy of `o`, intending to leave the members of `o` untouched.

Comment: Seems like weird program design. This kind of method *would* make sense if we frequently need to call an instance method straight after `modifyObject`. But in the top example you've given, no, it's not adding anything useful.

Comment: If it is not *specified in documentation* that the same object is returned but just a modified object, then the it leaves the developer free to use the implementation you show and then a different implementation in the next version of the method where a different object will be returned. Message: even though at present the same object is returned, *don’t rely on that always happening*. Also a subclass could do differently from the superclass, you don’t know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in another answer, returning the object after modification allows [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872222/how-to-do-method-chaining-in-java-o-m1-m2-m3-m4).

However, then the author of the code could as well had done

```
SomeObject modifyObject(SomeObject o){
    
    //do some magic that modifies o
    return o;
}
```

So either the code in `do some magic that modifies p` in the past was creating a new instance under certain circumstances like this

```
SomeObject p = o;
if (someCondition) {
    p = new SomeObject()
}
```

or the author thought that

```
SomeObject p = o;
```

creates a new instance `p` which is a copy of the object referenced by `o`, which however is not correct.

However to me it seems like there was some code changed in the past, without cleaning this up. Maybe you can check the git history to evaluate this.

Answer (score 4):

Because a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) enables *method chaining*.

```
SomeObject x = new SomeObject();
modifyObject(x).doSomethingElse().andAnotherThing();
```

Comment: But then, the author of the code could just have `return o`, correct?

Comment: @BenjyTec Well that would be cleaner to read, but `p` and `o` are references to the same instance so that would be equivalent.

Comment: The point of the fluent interface might be even clearer when not declaring a variable `x` here, e.g. `modifyObject(new SomeObject()).doSomethingElse().andAnotherThing();`. Or we use `SomeObject x = modifyObject(new SomeObject());` to emphasize that we keep a reference to `x` only if we made the modification (compare with `SomeObject x = Objects.requireNonNull(someExpression());`)

Comment: @Holger I frequently see a `Builder` pattern implemented where the `Builder` uses a fluent interface and returns `this` (of the `Builder` type) until a `build()` method which returns the type being built.

Comment: Well, yes, that’s the most common way do design a builder. Even the Stream API fits into that pattern, though not a typical builder…